# Initializing pointer to array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++. Please see the following code:

```
//sample1
int arr[2]  = { 11, 22 };
int(*t)[2];
t = &arr;
cout << *t[0] << "\n";
cout << *t[1] << "\n";


//sample2
int arr2[2];
arr2[0] = { 33 };
arr2[1] = { 44 };
int(*t2)[2];
t2 = &arr2;
cout << *t2[0] << "\n";
cout << *t2[1] << "\n";


//sample3
int arr3[2];
arr3[0] = { 55 };
arr3[2] = { 66 };
int(*t3)[2];
t3 = &arr3;
cout << *t3[0] << "\n";
cout << *t3[1] << "\n";
```

// output

```
11
-858993460
33
-858993460
55
66
```

Can anyone tell me how to initializing a pointer to array？Sample3 is out of my understanding.

Comment: This is wrong: `arr3[2] = { 66 };`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the initialization of `arr`. You should read up on the precedence of the `*` and `[]` operators. (hint: it should be `(*arr)[0]` etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1) `[]` has more precedence than `*` so you need parenthesis in all those cases (cfr. [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)). If you don't use them, you're going to do pointer-arithmetic on arrays of 2 integers each (thus immediately getting out-of-range), e.g.

```
int(*t)[2]; // A pointer to an array of 2 integers
cout << t[0]; // The address of the array

[first_integer][second_integer] ... garbage memory ...
^

cout << t[1]; // The address of the array + sizeof(int[2])

[first_integer][second_integer] ... garbage memory ...
                               ^
cout << *t[0]; // Dereference at the address of the array
cout << *t[1]; // Dereference past the end of the array

//  ---- correct -----

cout << (*t)[0]; // Dereference the pointer to the array and get the element there

[first_integer][second_integer] ... garbage memory ...
^

cout << (*t)[1]; // Dereference the pointer to the array and get the second element there

[first_integer][second_integer] ... garbage memory ...
               ^
```

2) You have an out-of-range access at line

```
arr3[2] = { 66 };
```

This is how you should proceed:

```
//sample1
int arr[2] = { 11, 22 };
int(*t)[2];
t = &arr;
cout << (*t)[0] << "\n";
cout << (*t)[1] << "\n";


//sample2
int arr2[2];
arr2[0] = { 33 };
arr2[1] = { 44 };
int(*t2)[2];
t2 = &arr2;
cout << (*t2)[0] << "\n";
cout << (*t2)[1] << "\n";


//sample3
int arr3[2];
arr3[0] = { 55 };
arr3[1] = { 66 };
int(*t3)[2];
t3 = &arr3;
cout << (*t3)[0] << "\n";
cout << (*t3)[1] << "\n";
```

The initialization is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

An array is almost the same thing as a pointer:

```
int arr[2]  = { 11, 22 };
int * t;
t = arr;
cout << t[0] << "\n";
cout << t[1] << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code snippet

```
//sample3
int arr3[2];
arr3[0] = { 55 };
arr3[2] = { 66 };
int(*t3)[2];
t3 = &arr3;
cout << *t3[0] << "\n";
cout << *t3[1] << "\n";
```

there is defined an array with two elements. The valid range of indices for elements of this array is `0, 1`
In this statement

```
arr3[2] = { 66 };
```

there is an attempt to write data beyond the array because index 2 is invalid. So you have

```
arr3: | 55 | uninitilaized | 66 |
index:   0        1          beyond the array
```

After these statements

```
int(*t3)[2];
t3 = &arr3;
```

pointer t3 points to array arr3,

Expression

```
t3[0]
```

gives array arr3

Expression

```
*t3[0]
```

gives the first element of the array. Thus statement

```
cout << *t3[0] << "\n";
```

outputs 55.

Expression

```
t3[1]
```

points to memory after (beyond) array arr3. You wrote at this address value 66. So this value is outputed by statement

```
cout << *t3[1] << "\n";
```

Of course this code snippet is invalid because its overwrite memory that was not reserved for objects of the code.